# Redirect TCP/IP to COM port driver

Tags: windows, networking, redirection, tcpip, serial-port

There are many programs which emulate a COM port and let you redirect it to an ethernet port. I want to do the opposite of that. Create a virtual ethernet port that redirects to a physical COM port. Are there any programs for this? I am a programmer; maybe a some source that would give me a starting point to write something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Whu not use PPP (It's IP over serial)? or PPP + sone ethernet tunnel l2tp+BCP or EoIP (https://code.google.com/p/linux-eoip/)